# How to get the current browser resolution in css?

Tags: css, browser, web

Can some one explain me how to get the current browser viewing resolution in css ?.
i want to make my website fit viwers resolution , how can i do that ?

Comment: You can't get this information using CSS. You can use javascript to get this information, using innerWidth and innerHeight properties for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as u explicitly provide a width and height to body of html its fits the entire screen width , css had no way to obtain width and height of screen but you can go by % and specify height and width as a % so that it would fit in any size screen.

eg :

```
html, body {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width:100%
    height:100%;
    width:100%

}
```

This sets the body take up full space of the screen even if there is no content to display.